# If the second derivative $f''(x)\ge 0$ then $f(\frac{a+b}{2})\le \frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

If the second derivative $f''(x)\ge 0$ then $f(\frac{a+b}{2})\le \frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}$

how to prove this inequality is we prove by using means values theorem and
f is differentiable $f'(x)\ge 0$ then  f is monotonic..need help please

Answer (score 1):

If $f^{\prime\prime}\ge 0$, then $f$ is convex, so the inquality in question (called *Jensen Inequality*) holds.

More directly, it could be proved that by $f^{\prime\prime}\ge 0$ the differential quotients are nondecreasing. Then write two quotients: at $a,\dfrac{a+b}{2}$ and at $\dfrac{a+b}{2},b$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $a<b$. Then $f((a+b)/2)-f(a)=f'(\xi_{1})((b-a)/2)$ and $f(b)-f((a+b)/2)=f'(\xi_{2})((b-a)/2)$, where $\xi_{1}$ in between $a<(a+b)/2$ and $\xi_{2}$ in between $(a+b)/2<b$, then do Mean Value Again to $f'(\xi_{2})-f'(\xi_{1})$.